# Options for building xml files as output files

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm beginner with Visual Studio and C#. I have already developed a program in which some data are read from two different .xml files "123456" and "HelloWorld" (see screenshot below). [image]

However, when I compile the program I can not see these files (see next screenshot) and manipulate them. There is any way to compile the program without compiling these files or should I change only the directory where these files are located. I would appreciate your help because it is the first time that I'm compiling a program in Visual Studio. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding XML Files to the Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326436/adding-xml-files-to-the-build)

Comment: One way would be to mark the xml files as "Content" and "copy if newer" in their properties in Visual Studio solution explorer..

Comment: Just change folder.  The files that appear in first list is from you bin folder.  The xml files are output files so you may just want to put in the bin folder if they are getting deployed with the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the following on the files you want to output

```
RightClick File->Properties->Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always/Copy Newer
```